# Don't miss me for I come first and last, Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, knowledge

> *Don't miss me for I come first and last,
>
>   yet third still fits me well.
>
>   Remember the key,
>
>   I'm in between San Francisco.
>
>   My oh my,
>
>   I hope this is not too easy.
>
>   Family comes first,
>
>   a quote to keep in mind.
>
>   Song me a sing,
>
>   I can be on girls and guitars.
>
>   Lucky me, why is it you?
>
>   Tik tok, take your time and take it slow,
>
>   even alone I can be black and yellow.
>
>   Don't miss me for I come last and first,
>
>   yet third still fits me well.*

Edit: Added knowledge tag, but it's really REALLY basic knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you are:

> The musical scale, C-D-E-F-G-A-B-C.

Don't miss me for I come first and last,
yet third still fits me well.

> The first note is C, and comes first and last.
>  C is the third letter of the alphabet.

Remember the key,
I'm in between San Francisco.

> The key on the keyboard between S and F is D.

My oh my,
I hope this is not too easy.

> "Easy" is pronounced EZ. Not sure about this line.

Family comes first,
a quote to keep in mind.

> F is the first letter of "family". Not sure what the "quote" is.

Song me a sing,
I can be on girls and guitars.

> Girls and guitars both have "G"s. And can also both have G-strings.

Lucky me, why is it you?

> Not sure about this line.

Tik tok, take your time and take it slow,
even alone I can be black and yellow.

> Bees are black and yellow.

Don't miss me for I come last and first,
yet third still fits me well.

> Once again.

As additional confirmation:

> The first letters of each set of lines are Do-Re-My[sic]-Fa-So-Lu[sic]-Ti-Do. This is an allusion to [solfege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge).

Comment: C is the third letter of the alphabet ;)

Comment: Typo fixed. Thanks for catching it. Anyone have any ideas on "Lucky me", "quote", and "too easy"?

Comment: "quote" is perhaps just surface reading (it looks like it).  I thought easy was eeeeee-sy to figure out.  No clue about lucky me.

Comment: Nice catch! Family refers to how these 8 notes belong in a "family"
Also, "Lucky me, why is it you?" the letter "U" in lucky is pronounced like "A".

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The letter T (Tea)

Explanation

Don't miss me for I come first and last,

yet third still fits me well.

> T is the only letter that is present in first, last and third

Remember the key,

I'm in between San Francisco.

My oh my,

I hope this is not too easy.

Family comes first,

a quote to keep in mind.

Song me a sing,

I can be on girls and guitars.

> May be refering to T-Guitars and t-girls (transgender)

Lucky me, why is it you?

Tik tok, take your time and take it slow,

> T is in tik and tok. Also t is used to represent time in physics

even alone I can be black and yellow.

> t alone can represent the word tea and tea can be of black (black tea) or yellow (milk tea)

Don't miss me for I come last and first,

yet third still fits me well.

Comment: I agree that a letter seems likely, but other parts of the riddle seem to suggest other letters. (Perhaps different bits point to different letters and we are meant to put them together?)

Comment: Oh. Ok ok. I thought each line hints same item. :(

Comment: I don't know. That would be the most usual thing, and it's a fair assumption -- but don't you think the black and yellow is most likely a B(ee), and the thing on girls and guitars I fear is a G(-string). (Though girls might wear *bee*hive hairdos, though they've been way out of fashion for decades, and guitars have B-strings...)

Comment: Aha -- see edderiofer's answer. Different letters, indeed.